# Почему в MS Edge на странице поддомена доступны куки не только этого поддомена, но и домена тоже?

Tags: javascript, cookie, microsoft-edge

Есть домен `example.com`

Есть поддомен `subdomain.example.com`

Когда устанавливаю куки из JS, с явным указанием `domain=example.com`, они автоматически появляются на `subdomain.example.com`.

Таким поведением обладает только MS Edge. Кто-нибудь знает, в чем тут дело?

Comment: Можно узнать domain параметр кук ?

Comment: Куки устанавливаются на JS. Domain автоматически проставляется в соответствии с тем на какой странице находится пользователь. Поэтому для кук с домена www.domain.com параметр domain = domain.com. Для www.subdomain.domain.com, domain = subdomain.domain.com.

Comment: Я подправлю вопрос - сейчас он создает впечатление, что кука ставится на www.example.com, и видна при этом на www.subdomain.example.com.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Это просто особенность механизма сопоставления domain в разных браузерах.

Edge, судя по всему, следует текущему Proposed Standard, [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3) от 2011 года. В нем правила проверки доменов следующие:

> 5.1.3.  Domain Matching
>
> A string domain-matches a given domain string if at least one of
> the    following conditions hold:
>
> o  The domain string and the string are identical.  (Note that both
> the domain string and the string will have been canonicalized to
> lower case at this point.)
>
> o  All of the following conditions hold:
>
> ```
>   *  The domain string is a suffix of the string.
>
>   *  The last character of the string that is not included in the
>      domain string is a %x2E (".") character.
>
>   *  The string is a host name (i.e., not an IP address).
> ```

Т.е. кука, поставленная с явным указанием домена, всегда доступна в субдомене. И это нормально.

Куки, для которых домен не был указан, устанавливаются с host-only-flag, который ограничивает их доступность только текущим доменом (без сабдоменов).

---

*Не столь современные браузеры*, пытаются следовать устаревшему [RFC2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965) от 2000-го года, в котором проверка выглядела немного хитрее:

> Host A's name domain-matches host B's if
>
> ```
>   *  their host name strings string-compare equal; or
>
>   * A is a HDN string and has the form NB, where N is a non-empty
>      name string, B has the form .B', and B' is a HDN string.  (So,
>      x.y.com domain-matches .Y.com but not Y.com.)
> ```

Т.е. сабдомены видели куки от основного домена только в том случае, если значение domain у куки начиналось с точки.

Хитрость заключалась в том, что браузер был *обязан* дописать точку в значение domain.

> If an explicitly specified value does not start with a dot, the user agent supplies a leading dot.

но *только в случае*, если домен выставлялся через заголовок Set-Cookie.

Если домен не был явно задан - то кука ставилась на домен без . в начале, и была недоступна для сабдоменов. Что приносило веселейшие баги в Chrome, когда кука на клиенте была поставлена одновременно с точкой и без точки, и удалить ее с сервера было невозможно.

Случай же установки куки через `document.cookie` стандарт не покрывал. Какие-то браузеры (IE/Edge) дописывают точку автоматом. Какие-то - ожидают, что вы допишите ее перед domain вручную.

В любом случае, RFC2965 устарел, так что рано или позно все куки станут видны сабдоменам. В соседнем ответе есть ссылка на [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#new-cookie_domain), и даже там уже сказано

> Contrary to earlier specifications, leading dots in domain names are ignored. If a domain is specified, subdomains are always included.

Answer (score 6):

Если вы задаёте куку с указанием домена:

```
document.cookie = "test=1; path=/; domain=example.com";
```

То, по-умолчанию, на поддоменах включая `subdomain.example.com` эта [кука тоже будет видна](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#new-cookie_domain).

Если вам нужно чтобы кука была видна только на текущем домене, то, согласно документации, вам вообще не нужно указывать какой-либо домен. Например, так:

```
document.cookie = "test=1; path=/";
```

Comment: Именно так я и указываю: 
`document.cookie = "test=1; path=/";`
Но в Edge куки все равно видна на поддомене.